# RFIDリーダーと接続できない

Tags: シリアル通信

**RFIDリーダーと接続できない**

ThingMagicのRFIDリーダー，M6E Nanoを使用していますが，接続出来ません。UniversalReaderAssistantやAPIを用いて接続を試みていますが，認識をしません。APIと通信したときの通信内容を見てみたところ，APIからの送信データは5Byte固定で9回送信していました。何度か接続を試みているものと見られます。しかし，リーダーから返ってくるデータは，長さ（大体180~190byte），中身が毎回バラバラで，規則性が全くありません。これはRFIDリーダーの故障でしょうか？

＜詳細情報＞
[image: RFID通信プロトコル説明]

通信プロトコルはこのようになっており，APIからの送信データはFF 00 03 1D 0Cの5バイトでDATAが0Bで送信されているとみられます。
リーダーからの応答は
FF CF 5D AD EF 6D 29 CD CF 78 B6 DB EF 88 FF BF DD 99 B7 F5 6D BF FF F7 D9 DA DB 2B 2D 69 B7 AD B5 D9 A5 69 DD BE 2B 6B 5B DA DB E6 FF FE 9B EF B5 99 DF 39 D1 98 E7 FF FD AE 2D 6F F5 AB DF FB F5 5B CF 7D FB FB DF 6B B5 A7 DB DE CF DF 7B FB 1C E3 7B F3 EE 5A 6B 5F 17 36 9A C6 17 FE FB 6F B6 5D FB 3D 9F 3C 77 6B 7D ED DF B5 65 6B ED AD 99 DB C0 5C 9F F3 EB FB FD 6A 6D A6 CB DA 6B FF EB B5 53 FF 77 E5 F5 F6 D2 B2 FB DA FE 7D 58 BB AD B5 D9 7F FF F7 6B 57 F7 DB D5 6B FF 4B 96 9F F2 3F DA 8E 49 7A 0F F6 FD DF B7 ED DD DB 2B 6B F7 3E DC 50 E2 F7 A6 E9 B9 5B DB CB D3 FF
や
EF EE F8 D9 12 30 66 5D D9 D3 8E FA 6D ED DB 4B F3 F9 EB 0C 78 E7 6B B5 B5 50 E8 6B F4 F7 EA D7 76 02 EE B8 FF E2 FC 7E 62 E2 75 22 0F E6 EB 4B 8F 26 67 BB 7F EF D4 98 7C F3 F5 9B FF 37 9E E6 BD EF B6 DD 3E AE D7 97 5E AD BF FF 32 EE FE EF FF 1F F9 F4 9A 88 8A F8 D8 6E E9 A9 77 6E 6F F8 E8 72 CE 4C 5E 6D 75 AB E7 FF 23 57 B9 37 5A 5B 33 79 FF F4 FD B6 E6 CE DD BF CD DB 6F B3 D9 BD B3 FE 9C 7B 93 62 7B 68 FF 1D FF 2E 99 DB FF DB 55 BD B2 97 0E 57 6F 3E 72 EF F7 ED 77 6E FF 10 FF 6E FF FF C4 C4 F4 36 9E 23 F2 3C FC D2 E3 7C 4C ED A6 66 75 5B FF AF
など，比べると分かりますが，規則性がありません。

[image: シリアル通信監視ソフト]

シリアル通信の監視ソフト設定はこのようになっています。WSL上でコマンドを実行し，返ってきたデータを監視しています。

Comment: 当該 M6E nano は調歩同期式っぽいですね（カタログは見つけたけど仕様書はユーザー登録が必要そうなのでダウンロードしてない）通信速度や条件は選択可能っぽいのですが、あってますか？調歩同期式で通信条件があっていないと「一見できているっぽいが、読み取ると意味不明」（今の状況）になっちゃいます。

Comment: 日本語の記事はこんなの [ThingMagic M6e Nano を使用した UHF 帯 RFID の制御](https://qiita.com/Mynah/items/447ec6da6acdcf9cb11f) が見つかります。WSLとかの複雑な仮想環境からの間接的なものではなくWindowsかLinux系の何かから直接やってみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: @774RR さん ＞ API側，モニターソフトともに通信速度は115200bpsで合わせています。現在キャラクタ長，パリティ，ストップビットの条件を変えつつテスト中です。（仕様書では，APIの使用が推奨されており，上記の仕様について触れられていませんでした。）
また，2つ目の画像にある，メモリモード，接続タイプ（直結／中継）も読み取りに影響しますか？

Comment: @kunif さん ＞ Linuxは，ドライバーがうまく入っていないのか，リーダー自体が認識できませんでした。Windows上では，UniversalReaderAssistantというソフトが出ていたので，このソフトを用いてデータを送信してチェックしてみましたが，ダメでした。今後Windows用のAPIや，Arduino用のライブラリでも試してみます。

Comment: 自己解決しました。
PCとの接続にCH340C（[www.sparkfun.com/products/15096](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15096)）を用いていたのですが，5Vのジャンパに変更する際，3.3Vの線を切断し忘れていたのが原因でした。また，PC供給の電源では電力が足りなかったため，セルフパワーのUSBハブを経由してPCに接続したところ，正しく認識，使用できました。